# What is the meta property="bf:buzzid"

Tags: html, meta

On the page https://www.buzzfeed.com/gabrielsanchez/voila-a-quoi-ressemble-le-changement-climatique-a-travers, there is a meta I have never seen, property bf:buzzid

```
<meta property="bf:buzzid" content="4550088" />
```

What is this meta and does it have a social sharing role related to buzzfeed or facebook ?

Comment: Just guessing `bf` is an acronym for `buzzfeed` and the `content` is their id for the content represented within. This is probably used as some OpenGraph-style consumable. `meta` tags are simply a way of marking up the document with "metadata about itself": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

Comment: I see but other known open Graph are "known" by everybody. Here I wonder if it's usable by anybody or it's a way to communicate for buzzfeed with some social networks in a "proprietary way"